# How to transfer multiple, random values of one list to another?

Tags: python

I am not sure how to transfer random, multiple(but not all of them) values in a list to another list. I know how to use pop to transfer one random value, but I want to be able to do multiple values.

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
x = list.pop(random.randint(0,len(mylist)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: don't call your variable `list` it hides python's builtin in `list` type.

```
lst = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

The `random` module provides mechanisms for randomising sequences, e.g. you can transform in place with `random.shuffle()`:

```
In [1]:
random.shuffle(lst)
lst

Out[1]:
['3', '1', '2', '5', '4']
```

Or to create a new list:

```
In [2]:
x = random.sample(lst, k=len(lst))
x

Out[2]:
['4', '5', '3', '2', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code in a `for-loop` like:

```
lst = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
lst2 = []
for _ in xrange(len(lst)):
    lst2.append(lst.pop(random.randint(0, len(lst)-1)))
print lst2
```

output:

```
['3', '2', '5', '4', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to move some of the elements to another array.
Lets say you want to move N elements:

```
mylist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
newlist = []
for i in range(N):
   myrand = random.randint(0,len(mylist))
   newlist.append(mylist.pop(myrand))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @AChampion's apporach, but using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [str(x) for x in range(6) if x > 0]
np.random.shuffle(lst)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['3', '1', '4', '5', '2']
```

If you can also try `np.random.choice`, which provide you more options (e.g. size, with/without replacement and probabilities associated with each entry).

```
lst = [str(x) for x in range(6) if x > 0]
new_lst = list(np.random.choice(lst, size=4, replace=False))
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
['4', '5', '3', '1']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
destination = []
n = 3 # i want to transfer 3 random numbers to another list
for _ in range(n):
    destination.append(source.pop(random.choice(list(range(len(source)-1))
```

### list(range(len(source)))

this creates a list of all the indexes of source
so that you can choose a random one for using pop and give the popped value to the destination list

### random.choice

it picks a random value from the given list

### list.append( other_list.pop() )

in one line, it pops a value from other_list and appends to the list object

Comment: This doesn't work. a) `list` object has no `shuffle()` function b) you've redefined `shuffle`. c) `random.shuffle()` modifies the list in place so `mylist.copy()` would be shuffled but you have not assigned a variable to `mylist.copy()`, d) `random.shuffle()` returns `None`